# white space below footer

Tags: html, css

There seems to be random white space after the footer at the bottom of the site. When I try to use inspect element, the white space doesn't seem to fall under any tags. It doesn't seem tied to any footer tags either as removing them didn't change anything.

I'm using [Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer solution](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) for my footer.

You can test it at: http://www.edmhunters.com/martin-garrix/

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your element with id `edmhunters-body` has to much `margin-bottom`

Comment: @putvande As mentioned i'm using Ryan Fait's sticky footer solution. And adding a negative margin bottom to the container equal to the size of footer is a part of that.

Comment: But you used too much.

Comment: Are you sure this is not meant to work like this? If you change the margin, the footer still works the same

Comment: try to include "display:none" instead of "visibility:hidden" to the id "_atssh" to get this fixed

Comment: check my answer, it should help.

Comment: @Aru Thanks, that did the trick. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to include `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden` to the id `_atssh` to get this fixed

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it, it will eliminate the white space at the bottom.

**Change**

```
footer {
width: 100%;
/* height: 150px; */
padding: 10px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
height: 100%;
}
```

**To**

```
footer {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 10px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have to keep the visibility property but you should use display none here:

```
<div id="_atssh" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
```